# How do you continue firing an event that is trigger by another button.

Tags: jquery, events, event-propagation

So i have multiple submit button.

```
    <input type="submit" id="addItem" value="Add Item" action="/addItem.php"/>
    <input type="submit" id="removeItem" value="Remove Item" action="/removeItem.php/>

    <input type="button" id="continue" value="Continue" style="display:none;/>
```

And than i have a jquery event

```
$("#addItem").click(function(event) {
     event.stopPropgation();

     $("#continue").show();
 });
```

Now when i click on continue i want to be able to continue firing of say addItem... (i could have more buttons on that page, and I can't use $(this).closest("form") cause I do not know which item is pressed.

How would i do this?

Comment: "i want to be able to continue firing of say addItem". You mean you want to submit the form?

Comment: You could add a data field to $("#continue") that stores the needed information

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery to change your form action.  Allowing your `submit` to be different based on your add/remove toggle buttons.

```
var myFormAction = "";

$("#addItem").click(function(event) {
     event.stopPropgation();

     myFormAction = "/addItem.php";

     $("#continue").show();
 });

$("#removeItem").click(function(event) {
     event.stopPropgation();

      myFormAction = "/removeItem.php";

     $("#continue").show();
 });

$("#continue").click(function(event) {
     //Open Dialog
 });
```

Comment: hi thanks except  i don't know the name of the input. These ids and actions are generated by 3rd party library framework. I only have the class $(".3rdPartySubmit").. so i want to go to each class add a event where once they click it would show a modal screen, than when they continue, it would continue through.

Comment: @user578635 So are you looking to just have a variable be available so you know which action to run on your modal dialog?

Comment: hi nope.. i want to be able to add a continue event .. click a debugger .. you know pause .. user enter some items, than hit continue.